# Oracle SQL - SELECT *, case

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.03

I am trying to run a Select * then have another column at the end that produces a new column with the specified results:

```
    select *, 
    case Column_1 when 'Employee' then 'Employee/Worker' 
    when 'Worker' then 'Employee/Worker' else Column_1 
    end as "TEST"
    from DB_TABLE
```

The results should be:

```
Column 1    Column 2   ......Test
Employee    Name             Employee/Worker
Worker      Name             Employee/Worker
Temp        Name             Temp
```

I have had it work in MS SQL, but can't get this working in Oracle.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: When you select * from this will work, but if you want to select *, col1, etc from table. you  need to qualify the * with table name or a table alias, that is the way oracle works here regardless of the tool you use say sql developer or sqlplus or toad etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this giving alias to table name

```
select dt.*, 
case when dt.Column_1 = 'Employee' then 'Employee/Worker'
     when dt.Column_1 = 'Worker'   then 'Employee/Worker'       
     else dt.Column_1  end TEST
from DB_TABLE dt
```

Comment: It's not the alias that will make this work, but the "qualified" `dt.*`. Should work without and alias an `dt_table.*` as well.